# mediaPlayer won't stop even if I finish the activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am in a situation where I have an ActivityGroup and inside of which I have an Activity in which I have used MediaPlayer to play an audio file. But when I navigate out of that Activity I am trying to stop the MediaPlayer, but unfortunately I was not able to do it. So I tried finishing my activity when I navigate out of it. I am able to finish the activity but still MediaPlayer doesn't stop at all.

How should I solve this.

Comment: For future reference when asking questions on Stack Overflow: 1) Provide a minimal code snippet that demonstrates the problem, and 2) Provide relevant context and use better tags like the fact that you're probably working on the Android platform based on the words in your question. Remember that we can't read your mind.

Comment: Ok.. I have found out the solution. I was messing up with ActivityGroup and Activities. Now I found out my mistake and have solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` won't stop when you finish your activity, you need to explicitly call `mMediaPlayer.stop()` in your activity's `onPause()`.

Comment: yes I have tried all the possibilities of stopping my MediaPlayer, but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: Do you have to put any code in `onResume()` to make `MediaPlayer` start again safely?